# Benefit of using controller function in the prototype

Tags: angularjs

In this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucassus/bpTXe/

what is the point of pointing the function **addTodo** in the prototype

```
TodosController.prototype = {
    addTodo: function() {
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you're looking at a sample from pre 1.0 angular, things were a bit more wild back then.